# Рекурсивный метод для вывода файлов с сохранением иерархии

Tags: java

Необходимо реализовать рекурсивный метод, который будет выводить список всех папок внутри папки, таким образом:

```
mainDir
|--dir1
|   |--dir11
|   |--dir12
|       |--dir121
|--dir2
|   |--dir23
|       |--dir231
|--dir3
```

В качестве аргумента можно принять только путь к самой папке, и никак не пойму как сделать "отступы" перед именами.

Comment: Необходимо - реализуйте! Или с чем-то есть более конкретные вопросы? Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Добрый день, проблема описана чуть выше, не понимаю как отобразить иерархию, если можно так сказать. То есть чтобы перед файлом находящимся на 2 уровня глубже было 4 пробела, а перед тем который на 3 - 6.

Comment: В рекурсивный метод передавайте значение отступа (количество пробелов). Для поддиректорий передавайте "текущее + 4". Для изначальной (`mainDir`) - 0. И судя по общей логике, с нулевым отступом `|` должно быть только в трёх строках (`dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3`)

Comment: Единственное что я могу передавать методу - путь к файлу, и больше ничего. Извиняюсь если непонятно выразился, когда писал это про это.

Comment: Откуда такое условие взялось? Вы же можете поменять сигнатуру метода? Можно не пробрасывать отступ в качестве параметра в метод, а хранить текущий отступ в виде, например, статического поля, но параметр метода - более предпочтительный вариант.